# Weird thing in file-descrpiter I/O for gpio port

Tags: c, file-io, embedded-linux, file-descriptor

I'm coding in Linux to control the gpio port on my board, using the following codes. However,the result from read() is always a 0x10, which is a hex for LF line feed. 
Voltage is an enum variable having int value of 0 and 1 standing for low and high.   fd is the file descripter for the gpio port. 0x30 is hex code for char '0'. There is no error in write().

```
int set_gpio( int fd,enum voltage_e voltage)
{
    const unsigned char w_buff =0x30+voltage;
    unsigned char r_buff='2';

    if (0 >= write(fd, &w_buff, 1))
    {
        LOGD(" Error1 in setting gpio to  %d", voltage);
        return -1;
    }
    __usr_sleep(0, 10000000);

    if (read(fd, &r_buff, 1))
    {
        if (r_buff != 0x30+voltage)
        {
            LOGD(" r_buff is %d", r_buff);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LOGD(" Error3 in setting gpio to %d", voltage);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What file is `fd` open to?

Comment: @duskwuff the fd is opened to a gpio port with path:/sys/calss/gpio/gpio102/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compatibility with shell utilities, the content of a GPIO port is typically a single character followed by a newline -- for instance:

```
% xxd /sys/class/gpio/gpio89/value
0000000: 310a                                     1.
```

Writing a single character to the GPIO device is advancing the file pointer to the second character, which is always the newline which you're seeing.

You will need to reset the file pointer to the beginning before doing a read/write operation:

```
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Ya. It works perfectly fine. However, I dont think it need a lseek before a further write, regardless of where the offset was. According to my new codes, the write will take effect right after a reading. Is it because that the file is limited to one byte thus a new write will replace the old content? or its because that write will start from the begining of the file?

Comment: btw, what's that "1." at the end of your output, before the long newline?

Comment: My guess would be the same as yours: the file pointer is ignored on `write()` to these files, as there's only one sensible place to write to. As far as `1.` goes, that's a text representation of the data. (A `.` is displayed instead of the newline.)